# Is installing .NET Framework needed?

Tags: c#, .net

I made a Windows Application in C#. Now, I have this question :

Is installing .NET Framework required for installing the Windows Application in other computers? Because it's gonna take a bit long time to install .NET Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. .NET Framework has to be installed in order to run your application.

Comment: Is it normal that it takes a bit long time?

Comment: If it is web installer than it depends on your connection

Comment: How "long" are we talking about?

Comment: Also, which version of .NET framework ? and are you using the standalone installer ? or pulling down the files from the internet every-time you run the installer ?

Comment: You can use bootstrapper for faster install.

Answer (score 0):

For Apps made in .Net Framework, yes .Net Framework is required.

If it is installing from a file on your file system then it is the fastest location to install your .Net Framework. Then installation speed depends on system speed. And yes it will take some time. .Net Framework 4.0 msi is ~ 40 MB

For Web-Installer, installation speed depends on internet-connection speed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally yes, but [this linker project](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/) may be able to get around this requirement.
I have never used this so don't know how effective it is, it may be worth a try though.